# Grails test-app Error creating bean with name 'grailsDatastore'

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am attempting to create tests for domain objects. The test is simple, see below. However it is throwing an error

*Error creating bean with name 'grailsDatastore'*

```
class AccountSpec extends Specification implements DataTest {

    void setupSpec(){
        mockDomain Account
    }

    void "test basic persistence mocking"() {
            setup:
            def account = new Account(name: 'Robert Fripp', username: "robert", password: "robert", email: "robert@mail.com").save(flush:true)

            expect:
            Account.count() == 1
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information to know for sure what is wrong with your project.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/mcroteauaccount.  That contains a test that does what you are trying to do:

https://github.com/jeffbrown/mcroteauaccount/blob/2110545083b3b41dca61eb77f1e4d5dfccc8508a/src/test/groovy/mcroteauaccount/AccountSpec.groovy

```
package mcroteauaccount

import grails.testing.gorm.DataTest
import spock.lang.Specification

class AccountSpec extends Specification implements DataTest {

    void setupSpec() {
        mockDomain Account
    }

    void "test basic persistence mocking"() {
        setup:
        def account = new Account(name: 'Robert Fripp', username: "robert", password: "robert", email: "robert@mail.com").save(flush: true)

        expect:
        Account.count() == 1
    }
}
```

That test compiles, runs, and passes.  If your question is how do you write a test which saves an instance and then verifies that the instance is included in what is returned from `Account.count()`, the code above demonstrates how to do that.